# How to iterate through a folder?

Tags: python

Unfortunately, I do not have any code for this, because I don't know how this would be done.
What I want to do is iterate through a **folder** (not directory) (named "images") and get all the images from that **folder** (not directory). Since these images will be added through a discord bot, I do not know how many images will be in that **folder** (not directory).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing solutions before posting. It is [as easy as writing `python` and then copying and pasting your question title after that, into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+How+to+iterate+through+a+folder%3F).

Comment: Did you try clicking the long link in my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import glob
glob.glob("path/to/folder/*.jpg")
```

you may change the file format to .png or any format you are using.

Comment: What does this return? A list?

Comment: "What does this return?" Did you **try it**? Did you try [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Comment: Yes, I tried reading the documentation. Yes, I tried it. But I was just curious...